# what will happen if you refresh the web browser?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-webpages

I have one doubt. I have a web application.It contains three tabs.when user click on each tab it will take to user to detail section of tab.In detail section one hyper link is present. When user click on that link it will take to corresponding section. There is back icon in my application so when click on it it will take the user to previous tab where he came. It is working fine .But if user refresh the page(User should be on page after click on hyperlink) what will be the action when click on application back button(not Browser back button).

1. @home tab or 2.Previous tab from where he came .

Comment: deponds on how the back icon href is set.

Comment: You are correct.If it is not refresh it will work fine .It will go to previous page. If we press F5 then what ever URL store in back button functionality it will reinitialize.Because page life cycle again start.